# Exclude taxonomy terms from search_excerpt in snippet

Tags: nodes, search

In search-result.tpl.php or in preprocess_search_result function, I want to keep $snippet. It is a great view to display search results.

But Apache Solr results, or Search module results, are displayed with terms that matches the query. These terms are designed to be hidden to anonymous. They can't be displayed in the snippet.

> ex: Marguerite **Duras** … histoire " avec **DURAS**. Celle de deux personnes qui se reconnaissent avant de se connaître. Une … "Qui est Marguerite **Duras** ?" Il avait découvert l'écrivain, il allait rencontrer la …

The term *Marguerite Duras* is an admin tag. By the way, it is nice that the score relevancy depends on it.

How is created the snippet, or search_excerpt ?  I tried the Taxonomy Hide module, but it doesn't affect search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search result is a node view and hence the `hook_node_view_alter` works for it.

So you would could create a custom module and write the following function

```
function custom_node_view_alter(&$build, $type)
{
    if (($build['#view_mode'] == 'search_result') && ($type = 'node'))
    {
        unset($build['field_tags']);
    }
}
```

change the `field_tags` to the name of your taxonomy field in the content type.

`$build['#view_mode']` this variable defines the view we are on. In this case we are on the search_result view. And the `$type` defines the module in this case it is the node.

Use the following for Drupal 6

```
function custom_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3, $a4) {


  switch ($op) {
     case 'search result':
          $node = node_load($node->nid);
        $node->build_mode = NODE_BUILD_SEARCH_RESULT;
        $node = node_build_content($node, FALSE, FALSE);
        $node->body = drupal_render($node->content);
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for you fast answer. I totally forgot to mention that I'm using Drupal 6 and it seems that hook_node_view_alter comes with the 7.x version.

Comment: in drupal 6 it is hook_nodeapi and the $op would be view

Comment: In fact there is an $op for search_result like in node view alter: [source](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6)

Comment: In 6 when it comes to the "search result" the taxonomy is already added to the body. so if you are OK with hacking the code then in the node.module near line number 1307 you have the code that add the taxonomy to the snippet you can comment that out if you want. :-)

Comment: It does not affect search results ($op = search result OR $op = view). I'm thinking of using apachesolr_search_snippets but I can't find good information on it. On hook_nodeapi neither… Please could you give me a hint?

Comment: Yes, yesterday, hacking the code is what I did in the first place commenting "Fetch terms for snippet". But after flushing caches, nothing changed. Do I need to re-save all nodes?

Comment: I have updated with the drupal 6 code let me know if that works for you

Comment: oups I tried to put your function in my theme, I need to create custom module… I tell you soon. Thanks for all you time, btw.

Comment: No, it doesn't work, but maybe it's the naming in my customresults module: I called the function-> function customresults_nodeapi and I add $node->body .= 'blah'; before the break; but nothing happens. Maybe Apache Solr module uses hook_nodeapi function and overrides the behaviour of my module.

Comment: could you post the complete code

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8ScUkbQ5

Comment: looks fine to me. remove the $node->body .= 'blah'; and you also dont need the  drupal_set_message("<pre>" . print_r($op,true) . "</pre>"); Have you cleared the cache?

Comment: Yes, it looks fine to me too. All caches cleared… but results not altered. Is there a way to know, if the function is called, with devel of a console log?

Comment: when you placed the drupal_set_message("<pre>" . print_r($op,true) . "</pre>"); code did you see any result in a green box?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7185/discussion-between-mohammed-shameem-and-elektrorl)